# How to click multiple elements in webpage that change the webpage with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, click

Every element that I want to click changes the web-page by creating more elements. When I click the first, no problem. On the second element that has to be clicked, an `ElementClickInterceptedException` is raised, because the element has changed positions because of the first clicking. How do I click all elements without exceptions?
This is my code:

```py
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.something')
for i in elements:
    i.click()
```

that brings up this error:

```py
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted:
Element <div class="something">...</div> is not clickable at point (5, 5). Other element would
receive the click: <div class="another_thing">...</div>
```

Comment: @DebanjanB My question is not the same as the one you pointed at and couldn't be solved by the way described because the problem is different.  My problem: elements move after click. The problem in the other question: element is overlapped by another element

Comment: How can we imagine your question without **a clear problem statement**? See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @DebanjanB my question is minimal, complete and reproductible, with every needed detail posted. I wrote that "an ElementClickInterceptedException is raised, because the element has **changed** positions because of the first clicking" I didn't mention any overlaps. But I get it they look alike